# Python Problem: Unable to access option in program

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I keep recieving an TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object when I select option 4 in the menu. How do I fix this, I have tried for hours with no success. Code is below:

```
from turtle import right
def selection_sort(altered_number_list, sorting_order):
    if sorting_order == 1:
        for value in range (0, len(altered_number_list)-1):
            least_value = value
            for index in range (value+1, len(altered_number_list)):
                if altered_number_list[index] < altered_number_list[least_value]:
                    altered_number_list[index], altered_number_list[least_value] = altered_number_list[least_value], altered_number_list[index]           
        return altered_number_list
    else: 
        for value in range (0, len(altered_number_list)-1):
            least_value = value
            for index in range (value+1, len(altered_number_list)):
                if altered_number_list[index] > altered_number_list[least_value]:
                    altered_number_list[index], altered_number_list[least_value] = altered_number_list[least_value], altered_number_list[index]
            return altered_number_list
def bubble_sort(altered_number_list, sorting_order):
    if sorting_order == 1:
        for value in range (len(altered_number_list)):
            for index in range (0, len(altered_number_list)-1):
                if altered_number_list[index] > altered_number_list[index+1]:
                    altered_number_list[index], altered_number_list[index+1] = altered_number_list[index+1], altered_number_list[index]
        return altered_number_list
    else: 
        for value in range (len(altered_number_list)):
            for index in range (0, len(altered_number_list)-1):
                if altered_number_list[index] < altered_number_list[index+1]:
                    altered_number_list[index], altered_number_list[index+1] = altered_number_list[index+1], altered_number_list[index]
        return altered_number_list

def insertion_sort(altered_number_list, sorting_order):
    if sorting_order == 1:
        for value in range(1, len(altered_number_list)):
            insert_value = number_list[value]
            data_switch = value
            while data_switch > 0 and altered_number_list[data_switch-1] > insert_value:
                altered_number_list[data_switch] = altered_number_list[data_switch-1]
                data_switch -= 1
            altered_number_list[data_switch] = insert_value
        return altered_number_list
    else: 
        for value in range(1, len(altered_number_list)):
            insert_value = number_list[value]
            data_switch = value
            while data_switch > 0 and altered_number_list[data_switch-1] < insert_value:
                altered_number_list[data_switch] = altered_number_list[data_switch-1]
                data_switch -= 1
            altered_number_list[data_switch] = insert_value
        return altered_number_list

def quick_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order):
    if number_list_min < number_list_max:
        split_value = partition_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order)
        quick_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, split_value-1, sorting_order)
        quick_sort(altered_number_list, split_value+1, number_list_max, sorting_order)

def partition_sort(alter_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order):
    if sorting_order == 1:
        pivot_value = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        left_value = number_list_min + 1
        right_value = number_list_max
        complete = False
        while not complete:
            while left_value <= right_value and alter_number_list[left_value] <= pivot_value:
                left_value = left_value + 1
            while alter_number_list[right_value] >= pivot_value and right_value >= left_value:
                right_value = right_value - 1
            if right_value < left_value:
                complete = True
            else:
                alter_number_list[left_value], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value], alter_number_list[left_value]
        alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        return alter_number_list
    else: 
        pivot_value = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        left_value = number_list_min + 1
        right_value = number_list_max
        complete = False
        while not complete:
            while left_value <= right_value and alter_number_list[left_value] >= pivot_value:
                left_value = left_value + 1
            while alter_number_list[right_value] <= pivot_value and right_value >= left_value:
                right_value = right_value - 1
            if right_value < left_value:
                complete = True
            else:
                alter_number_list[left_value], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value], alter_number_list[left_value]
        alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        return alter_number_list   

import random
print("This program will sort a list of random numbers using a user determined sorting algorithm.")
sorting_algorithms = ["Selection Sort", "Bubble Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Quick Sort"]
sorting_orders = ["Ascending", "Descending"]
number_list = []
while True:
    try:
        random_numbers = int(input("Input number of random integers generated: "))
        print("Sorting Algorithms: ")
        for sort in range (0, len(sorting_algorithms)):
            print(f"{sort+1} - {sorting_algorithms[sort]}") 
        sorting_algorithm = int(input("Select sorting algorithm: "))
        print("Sorting Orders: ")
        for sort in range (0, len(sorting_orders)):
            print(f"{sort+1} - {sorting_orders[sort]}") 
        sorting_order = int(input("Select sorting algorithm order: "))

        if random_numbers < 1 or random_numbers > 999999:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to 999999 are accepted.")
            continue
        elif sorting_algorithm < 1 or sorting_algorithm > 4:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to four are accepted.")
            continue
        elif sorting_order < 1 or sorting_order > 2:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to two are accepted.")
            continue

        for i in range(random_numbers):
            number_list.append(random.randint(0, 999999))
        print (number_list)
        
        number_list_min = 0
        number_list_max = len(number_list) - 1

        if sorting_algorithm == 1:
            altered_number_list = selection_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 2:
            altered_number_list = bubble_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 3:
            altered_number_list = insertion_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 4:
            altered_number_list = quick_sort(number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order)
            break 
    except:
        print("Invalid input, integer values in the program specified parameters are accepted.")
print(altered_number_list)
```

In the code above, I am able to access options 1, 2, and 3 with no difficulty but I am unable to access the 4th option as it displays an error message. At this point, I have tried renaming variables, using different loops and operations, and creating separate functions but I am still unable to access the 4th option which is the quick sort algorithm. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for the quick sort and partition sort:

```
def quick_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order):
    if number_list_min < number_list_max:
        split_value = partition_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order)
        quick_sort(altered_number_list, number_list_min, split_value-1, sorting_order)
        quick_sort(altered_number_list, split_value+1, number_list_max, sorting_order)

def partition_sort(alter_number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order):
    if sorting_order == 1:
        pivot_value = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        left_value = number_list_min + 1
        right_value = number_list_max
        complete = False
        while not complete:
            while left_value <= right_value and alter_number_list[left_value] <= pivot_value:
                left_value = left_value + 1
            while alter_number_list[right_value] >= pivot_value and right_value >= left_value:
                right_value = right_value - 1
            if right_value < left_value:
                complete = True
            else:
                alter_number_list[left_value], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value], alter_number_list[left_value]
        alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        return alter_number_list
    else: 
        pivot_value = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        left_value = number_list_min + 1
        right_value = number_list_max
        complete = False
        while not complete:
            while left_value <= right_value and alter_number_list[left_value] >= pivot_value:
                left_value = left_value + 1
            while alter_number_list[right_value] <= pivot_value and right_value >= left_value:
                right_value = right_value - 1
            if right_value < left_value:
                complete = True
            else:
                alter_number_list[left_value], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value], alter_number_list[left_value]
        alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
        return alter_number_list
```

I believe the main issue lies in the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        random_numbers = int(input("Input number of random integers generated: "))
        print("Sorting Algorithms: ")
        for sort in range (0, len(sorting_algorithms)):
            print(f"{sort+1} - {sorting_algorithms[sort]}") 
        sorting_algorithm = int(input("Select sorting algorithm: "))
        print("Sorting Orders: ")
        for sort in range (0, len(sorting_orders)):
            print(f"{sort+1} - {sorting_orders[sort]}") 
        sorting_order = int(input("Select sorting algorithm order: "))

        if random_numbers < 1 or random_numbers > 999999:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to 999999 are accepted.")
            continue
        elif sorting_algorithm < 1 or sorting_algorithm > 4:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to four are accepted.")
            continue
        elif sorting_order < 1 or sorting_order > 2:
            print("Invalid input, integer values greater then or equal to one and integer values less then or equal to two are accepted.")
            continue

        for i in range(random_numbers):
            number_list.append(random.randint(0, 999999))
        print (number_list)
        
        number_list_min = 0
        number_list_max = len(number_list) - 1

        if sorting_algorithm == 1:
            altered_number_list = selection_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 2:
            altered_number_list = bubble_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 3:
            altered_number_list = insertion_sort(number_list, sorting_order)
            break
        elif sorting_algorithm == 4:
            altered_number_list = quick_sort(number_list, number_list_min, number_list_max, sorting_order)
            break 
    except:
        print("Invalid input, integer values in the program specified parameters are accepted.")
```

Comment: can you provide a minimum reproducible example?https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just added the example!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question contains a large amount of code. It would really help if you could isolate the part of the code that produce the error. That's what we like to call a "minimum" reproducible example: not your original code in its totality, but a smaller code that reproduces the same error. It will make it more likely that someone will want to answer your question. It will also help future users who encounter the same issue with their code. And more importantly, isolating the error will help you understand and debug your own code.

Comment: BTW, I think the error is that you wrote an equal sign `=` instead of a comma `,` on that line: `alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]`

Comment: Note that the error message is usually longer than just "Cannot unpack non-iterable int value." The error message usually contains a full "trace" that tells you in which function and at which line the error occurred. That would make it easier to identify the error. But in this case, "Cannot unpack" is what happens when you try to write `a, b = c` and `c` does not "contain two elements". So I looked through your code for a line that looked like this pattern `a,b = c` and there was only one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

is most likely telling you that somewhere in your code, you must have a line that looks like:

```py
a, b = c
```

where `c` is an `int`, and thus cannot be split into `a` and `b` as if it were a pair.

There is only one line in your code that looks like this, and it is indeed suspicious:

```py
alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[number_list_min]
```

I believe you meant to swap the two values, and the second equal sign `=` should instead be a comma `,`:

```py
alter_number_list[number_list_min], alter_number_list[right_value] = alter_number_list[right_value], alter_number_list[number_list_min]
```

Note that the **full** error trace given by python usually includes more information than just this short error message. You should see a longer message telling you in which function and at which line the error occurred. Reading that full error message would have made it a lot faster to find the suspicious line in your code.